# Rails - html img tag error: 404 not found

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, http-status-code-404, asset-pipeline

Inside my rails project:

if i use the image_tag

```
<%=image_tag 'sqlite.png'%>
```

the image shows up, if however, i use the raw html img tag like so:

```
<img src="/assets/images/sqlite.png">
```

I also tried

```
<img src="/images/sqlite.png">
```

[image]

I still get the 404 - not found error. How do I use raw html image tags inside rails ?

For my specific use case, I need to use html img tag . Help!

Comment: Did you put sqlite.png inside assets/images? See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you add your images in app/assets/images/ and your code `<%= image_tag 'sqlite.png' %>` should be fine.

Your images:
`app/assets/images/sqlite.png`

In your code:

```
<%= image_tag 'sqlite.png' %>
```

HTML:

`<img src="/assets/sqlite.png" >`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Comment: Yes that is where i put the image, hence the rails code using image_tag helper works.
However I need to use raw html img tags like so: <img></img>. That is the problem. Using the the rails image_tag helper is not an option

Comment: @SUPERUSER please upvote if you got the right answer.

Comment: thanks, it was a silly mistake - i was using /images instead of /assets